# Replacing the session id then it is logging in

Tags: node.js, authentication, session, cookies, middleware

If there are two users Alice and Bob both logged in different browser,Now if i put alice's session id in bob's it is logging in.

I am using express-session in node.js but not able to fix the issue.If this happens it should go to login in page.

Comment: If Bob gets hold of Alice's session id, he can impersonate her, this cannot be avoided. You must avoid that Bob gets hold of Alice's session id in the first place. How did he do it in your example?

Comment: Currently the application is in local host for testing I did that manually but it must not do that in final product

Comment: Ask yourself whether Bob could ever do that in your final product. For example, if you store the session id in a secure httpOnly cookie, the answer should be "no".

Comment: I don't want that if  sessionid modified it must log out and ask for log in but I'm not able to do that.

Comment: No-one is able to do that. Sessions are authenticated by their session id. The server cannot know whether the client is a legitimate holder of the session id, because a typical client on the internet is anonymous. It's like your front door can be opened by anyone who has the key.